# Disable automatic currency update

Tags: cron, currency-rates

The cron does update the currency rates. But because we want to set them manually I would like to disable the updating of the currency rate.

How could I cancel the auto update of the currency rate but have the cron running?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to set the currency rates manually, you don't need to keep the cron running. When you want to set the new rates just click on the import button, adjust the values (if needed) and save them.
Also there is no way to have the cron running but not keep the values. They are not saved anywhere temporary. If you want this you might need heavy customization. You should create a new table, run the cron to save the values in your table and then retrieve them from there when you want to change the rates.
You can disable the cron from `System->Configuration->Currency Setup->Scheduled Import Settings`.

Comment: It is possible to make currency price automatically update in my admin side when currency rate is update using cronjob without import that price manually ??